# Deploy 2nd Gen Google Cloud Function from Cloud Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I currently work with 1st gen functions and successfully deploy using Cloud Source Repositories to connect the function to a Github repo, push code changes to the repo and then deploy the cloud function.

I have now built a 2nd generation function and have realized that the option to deploy from a cloud source repository doesn't exist for 2nd gen functions - as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-source-repo) - what are the steps I need to take to follow a similar workflow for a 2nd gen function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a Cloud Function from a source code repository, you need to use the Cloud Functions API or the gcloud command-line tool.
Clone the repository locally and deploy it.

Comment: Thank you, I've understood that what I'm trying to do is essentially not possible. Taking this approach. I've committed my code to github and am using 'gcloud functions deploy ...' to deploy from local.

Answer (score 4):

Deploying functions from Cloud Source Repositories is currently only supported in Cloud Functions (1st gen).Gen 2 functions have limited source repository support and thus cannot deploy below the top level of a Cloud Source Repository.

As deploying from Cloud Source Repositories is not supported for gen 2 functions there  is a bug raised for this at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/248110968) ,Which is still open further progress can be tracked there.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details in issue tracker - it's clear that it's currently not possible and there is no workaround/alternative way to directly connect a 2nd gen cloud function to a version control repo.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to build a custom solution that involves Cloud Build. With Cloud Build, you can easily execute any command, such as

> `gcloud function deploy`

The execution of the command via Cloud Build can be triggered through events such as commits to the Source Repository. You can have a look at general details about Cloud Build [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Google Cloud SDK.

Here is a Windows batch file you can use as an example.

```
@echo off

set NAME=name of cloud function

set GEN=gen2
set MEMORY=512MB
set RUNTIME=nodejs20
set PROJECT=project name
set REGION=us-central1

set REPO=repo name
set BRANCH=master

rem Specify the desired branch by appending /moveable-aliases/<branchName>, the desired tag with /fixed-aliases/<tagName>, or the desired commit with /revisions/<commit>

set SOURCE=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/%PROJECT%/repos/%REPO%/moveable-aliases/%BRANCH%
set ENTRY_POINT=main
set TIMEOUT=540s

call gcloud beta functions deploy %NAME%    ^
    --%GEN%                 ^
    --memory=%MEMORY%           ^
    --runtime=%RUNTIME%         ^
    --project %PROJECT%         ^
    --region=%REGION%           ^
    --source=%SOURCE%           ^
    --entry-point=%ENTRY_POINT%         ^
    --timeout=%TIMEOUT%         ^
    --set-env-vars=%ENV_VARS%       ^
    --trigger-http              ^
    --no-allow-unauthenticated      ^
    --max-instances=1


pause
```